# Name of (anti?)pattern: helper class to implement free function

Tags: terminology

Suppose we have a publicly declared function

```c++
Result ComputeResult(Foo foo);
```

whose implementation is complex and requires some temporary data structures. I might break the implementation down into steps to improve comprehension:

```c++
Result ComputeResult(Foo foo) {
  Result result;
  std::map<Bar, Baz> bar_to_baz;
  std::vector<Baz> extra_bazzes;
  GroupByBar(foo, &bar_to_baz, &extra_bazzes);
  AppendExtraBazzes(extra_bazzes, &bar_to_baz);
  ModifyBazzes(&bar_to_baz);
  // etc
  PopulateResult(bar_to_baz, &result);
  return result;
}
```

Passing the temporary structures around can get cumbersome, especially if the calls are nested; a parameter may only be indirectly relevant to the top level call. In some cases I find it more readable to define a helper class to hold them, instantiated once per function invocation:

```c++
class ResultComputer {
 public:
  ResultComputer(Foo foo) : foo_(foo) {}
  Result Compute() {
    GroupByBar();
    AppendExtraBazzes();
    ModifyBazzes();
    // etc
    PopulateResult();
    return result_;
  }
 private:
  void GroupByBar();
  void AppendExtraBazzes();
  void ModifyBazzes();
  void PopulateResult();

  Foo foo_;
  Result result_;
  std::map<Bar, Baz> bar_to_baz_;
  std::vector<Baz> extra_bazzes_;
};

Result ComputeResult(Foo foo) {
  return ResultComputer(foo).Compute();
}
```

I vaguely recall some advice about this but can't find it - I don't know what to search for. Does this pattern have a name?

---

Note: I'm not asking about the value of the pattern; that's a separate question. I'm certainly not asking for detailed comments on my (very contrived) example.

Comment: It is basically a little God Object - faced with a complicated task, a developer cannot decompose the intermediate data to logically distinct classes, instead placing whole state into single object.

Comment: That looks like putting an algorithm into a class of its own. I don't remember the term for that now.

Comment: Maybe in a generic sense, yes.  I think OP is specifically asking about what the pattern is in the context of how it is being used.

Comment: So in order to execute task A, you need to execute tasks B, C, and D.  Rather than have a bunch of doA, doB, doC methods, you create a helper class with only doA which transparently performs the acts of B, C, and D and thereby hiding the complexity?  I don't know if this is really a pattern.  Hiding complexity is more like a line of work than a pattern.

Comment: I see zero benefit of the `ResultComputer` class, only drawbacks. Members are  defined before they are used, as opposed to locals that can be declared at the point where they are initialised. All the `void DoStuff()` private methods hide the data dependancies. `Compute` probably should only be callable once per `ResultComputer`, but it's public so anyone can do it multiple times.

Comment: I like to think about them as a "temporary contexts". They are way to capture short-lived state. Strangely enough, it is a case of Parameter Object refactoring.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I would recommend keeping this helper class in as tight a scope as possible. Like a private inner class in Java or C# (not sure if that's feasible in C++).

Comment: @AndrewPiliser In C++ I would put this class in an unnamed namespace in the .cc file, which I think is roughly analogous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parameter Object](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) gives a name to refactoring, that groups multiple method arguments and helps with their propagation.

I never call them as such though.

Comment: Accepting this answer since there were no more specific suggestions (maybe there's no existing term for it). It feels a bit different from parameter object though because the object is not intended to be passed around or exposed publicly. I like "temporary contexts" as you mentioned in a comment.